# Question: How can I run TimeScaleDB on Docker on an ARM architecture with volumes?

Tags: docker, arm, timescaledb

How can I run TimeScale on Docker on a ARM architecture with the Postgres/TimescaleDB data volumes exposed to the host?

My idea was to do the following:

```
docker run -d --restart always \
--name timescaledb \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
-e POSTGRES_USER=user \
-e POSTGRES_DB=databasename \
-v /etc/postgresql:$PWD/postgres/etc \
-v /var/log/postgresql:$PWD/postgres/log \
-v /var/lib/postgresql:$PWD/postgres/lib \
timescale/timescaledb
```

However, TimescaleDB seems to be stuck in the start/ restart process:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions / ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Question is available on Github, too: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/issues/23

The docker log (`docker logs timescaledb`) tells the following:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Running

```
docker run \
--name timescaledb \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
-e POSTGRES_USER=user \
-e POSTGRES_DB=databasename \
timescale/timescaledb
```

returns the same error: `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Comment: Does `docker logs timescaledb` say anything interesting?  (Or running the container without the `-d --restart always` flags?)

Comment: Also, your `-v` options look kinda backwards: you're mounting your host's system log directory into `$PWD/postgres/log` in the container, which probably isn't what you intend.

Comment: Hi David, I will try and update the question. Actually, that's not what I want :D I want to mount the volumes from the container to the host...

Comment: I have tried the container without the volumes and the `-d --restart-always` but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I somehow totally missed the ARM part of the question...most Docker images are built for x86 targets and you need to find an ARM-specific image (or build your own).  That will definitely cause the `exec format error`.

Comment: I thought it was an universal image because the underlying Postgres image is universal, too: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will check if the image supports ARM architectures. Follow up for more information is here: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker/issues/25